# Disable Brightness Change when charging Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: display, battery, lenovo-laptop, brightness

I have a [Lenovo 320S-15IKB (Type 81BQ)](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/320s-15ikb-type-81bq) Ideapad Laptop.  This is a new laptop with latest versions of drivers and utilities installed.

When using the Intel Graphics app, I attach the charge cable, the Ideapad's screen gets brighter; when unplugged, it returns to the previous brightness level.   I want the screen not to change brightness when I plug in or unplug.   If I disable the Intel Graphics app, the Ideapad does not change brightness when the power state changes.

As you see in this screenshot, there's no option to change it in Windows Power Management software. There should be a pair of sliders for brightness as the third items, one under 'On battery' and another under 'Plugged in', but they're missing.

[image: Screenshot of all this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display of the *Brightness* slider [*should* be controlled by the Registry key](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108126-add-remove-display-brightness-power-options-windows.html)`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb` value DWORD *Attributes*. Set it to `2` to display the slider. However, that might *not* display the slider in some circumstances.

You can set the brightness through the Registry directly to work around that issue.

[image: Default Power Scheme brightness settings]

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>, type `rege` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open Regedit.
- Copy the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb` and paste it into the Regedit Search bar to go to that key.
- In the key `DefaultPowerSchemeValues` are sub-keys for `ACSettingIndex` and `DCSettingIndex` to adjust the percentage brightnes on mains power and on battery power, respectively. Set them for *each* GUID, so that all plans have the same brightness setting on battery and on mains.
- **N.B.** If a third-party app such as the *Toshiba eco utility* controls screen brightness, you may need to search the Registry for `ACSettingIndex` and change the values *there*, as well.

[image: Toshiba eco brightness settings]

Please let me know if either Registry setting resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me! I did 2 steps from that guide - https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108126-add-remove-display-brightness-power-options-windows.html#option2 (cmd / regedit) but still haven't slider for changing ( https://numload.com/OTUwMQ== here's my regedit state )

Comment: Maybe it's because of Intel Graphics?

Comment: I have Intel Graphics as well on my 20FB-CT01WW Thinkpad X01 Carbon, and the slider is present. So, it's not Intel, but an installation glitch or a bug on Lenovo's side.

Comment: Or third-party software hiding the slider.

Comment: Actually, those should just be *default* settings. If you hibernate, the brightness should just return to the last (manual) setting on starting up again.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was solved by disabling power saving options, **Extended Battery Life for Gaming** and **Display Power Saving Technology**, in Intel HD Graphics Control Panel

[image]